# How to tighten a swivel component on a shower head?

Tags: shower

So here's the situation. I got a shower head:

[image]

Problem is that the swivel part is loose, so the shower head just kinda flops down. Is there any way to tighten that part?

Any help/suggestions/links is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some models the rubber washer helps keep the swivel tight. Check if the grommet has been pushed into the pipe (when overtightened, sometimes they get squished inside the pipe).

Comment: Not quite the answer, but lead me in the right direction. Took off the shower head, examined it (including the role the grommet plays), and screwed it back on tighter. Way tighter.